# Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist

Tags: windows, mysql, windows-7

I installed MySql and when i try to start it , it stop with error 3534

here is my error from log

```
2016-05-19T19:29:20.416636Z 0 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.user' doesn't exist
```

and this my `my.ini`  config file

```
 basedir = "C:\\Apache24\\mysql\\"
    datadir = "D:\\web\\uRexpelled\\DB\\data\\"
    # port = .....
    # server_id = .....
```

How i should solve this problem?

Comment: Which MySQL version? Has the datadir been initialized correcly?

Comment: Sounds like the configuration never got finished. Have you run mysql_install_db after you peformed the initial installation?